# Как вызвать метод из другого класса?

Tags: c++

Если в вкратце обьяснить структуру кода то это будет так.

1. Родительские классы Army,State,Ability и Magic и InterfaceTheGame.
2. От Army наследуется SpellCaster от которого наследуется Warlock.
3. От State наследуется SpellCasterState.
4. От Ability -> NormalAbility.
5. От Magic -> WarlockMagic.
6. При вызове конструктора Warlock происходит агригация с классами SpellCasterState, NormalAbility, WarlockMagic.
7. Warlock может вызывать демонов, вызов и управление демонами написано в WarlockMagic. На игровой доске должен появляться демон, ему надо приписать координаты. Сеттер для координатор прописан в классе InterfaceTheGame.
8. Хотелось бы при создании Демона(в классе WarlockMagic) получать доступ к методу с InterfaceTheGame.

   ```
   void WarlockMagic::callDemon() {
       demons->insert(std::pair<int,Army*>(counter, new Soldier()));
       itDemon = demons->find(counter);
       InterfaceTheGame::setDemonLocation(itDemon->second,this->unit);
   }
   ```

при компиляции получаю такую ошибку:

```
WarlockMagic.cpp:22:23: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    InterfaceTheGame::setDemonLocation(itDemon->second,this->unit);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Если вы хотите именно так обращаться к методу, то почему бы его не сделать `static` или в вашей реализации предполагается наличие экземпляра класса  `InterfaceTheGame` (что, кстати говоря, будет странным, как минимум, исходя из названии класса)?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive изнаально это класс планировался быть визуализацией игрового поля и реализацией движения юнитов на поле, но сейчас там находиться много лишнего, поэтому тут или создать еще один класс или переименовать его)

Comment: При вызове конструктора происходит агрегация? Эээ...

Comment: @VladD ну простите меня, я только учусь. В конструкторе Warlock у меня к примеру this->state = new SpellcasterState(); this->magic = new WarlockMagic(); это же агрегирование? создание класса из существующих классов или я что то серьезно напутал?

Comment: Агрегация не происходит во время пробега конструктора, агрегация — это дизайн класса. То есть если вы в вашем дизайне предусматриваете, что в классе A есть поле типа B (или указатель на B, или ссылка на B) — это и есть агрегация. А то, как вы инициализируете это поле — технические подробности реализации этой самой агрегации.

Comment: @VladD понял) спасибо большое)